# TypeError Cannot read property 'price' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to have the current price of an item be the most recent bid in the array. I get this error but in the logs it shows what I'm looking for. Just taking a crack at it I'm assuming it's not actually there yet and thus giving me the error. Never encountered this issue before. Here's the code and thanks for looking.

```
const ListingItem = ({
  auth,
  deleteListing,
  listing: {
    _id,
    user,
    username,
    title,

    bids,

    imagePath,
    date
  }
}) => {


  return (
    <div className="listing-container">
      <Link className="link" to={`/profile/user/${user}`}>
        {console.log(_id)}
        <h4>{username}</h4>
      </Link>

      <p className="listing-1 listing-title">{title}</p>
      <div className="listing-image-container">
        <img src={imagePath} className="listing-image-container-image" />
      </div>

      <p className="listing-price">
        Price:
        {console.log(bids[0].price)}
      </p>
      <p className="listing-bids">Bids:{bids.length}</p>
      <p className="listing-date">
        Posted on <Moment format="MM/DD/YYYY">{date}</Moment>
      </p>

      {!auth.loading && user === auth.user._id && (
        <button
          onClick={() => deleteListing(_id)}
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-danger m-b"
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      )}
      {!auth.loading && user !== auth.user._id && <BidForm listingId={_id} />}
    </div>
  );
};

ListingItem.propTypes = {
  listing: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  deleteListing: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  user: state.user
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { deleteListing }
)(ListingItem);
```

Comment: What do you get if you console log `bids`? I bet it will be zero briefly

Comment: Yep empty then i get what im needing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manneskja has a good solution.

Personally though, I wouldn't conditionally render the whole `<p>` but probably opt to just not display the price value until it exists:

```
<p className="listing-price">Price: {bids[0] && bids[0].price}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add this before your first `return` if you want to wait until some other part of your program sets a value for `bids`:

```
if(!bids || bids.length === 0) return null;
```

Or you can wrap the price section like so:

```
{bids.length > 0 && <p className="listing-price">Price: {bids[0].price}</p>}
```